# How to solve: dependent Angular material DatePickers?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two angular material datepickers. With the first, the start date can be set, with the second the end date. After selecting the start date, how to disable selecting an earlier date as end date?

I have tried using [min]="value", also setting the min date from .ts, but non of them worked.

```
     <div class="form-group" >
    <mat-form-field>
      <input name="picker" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose shipping date"
        [(ngModel)]="details.date"  required>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input  name="picker2" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="Choose arrival date"
        [(ngModel)]="details.end_date" required>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker2 ></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

How to set the minimum value for the second datepicker, after selecting the start date with the first?

Answer (score 1):

You would take the first date's value `details.date` and set it as `min` for your second DatePicker: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api